# Django form inherit - change fields

Tags: python, django

I want to change the order of a NewForm field to have name first. But I have a situation below where my NewForm inherits from OldForm and this gives errors.

**ModelForm has no model class specified.**

However, I don't see why I should add the model in again.

```
class OldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = Address()

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('address')

class NewForm(OldForm):
    name = Name()


    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'address')
```

Comment: That's not a model form. I'm confused

Comment: @yuvi sorry error in my example I have changed it to reflect.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: ModelForm has no model class specified. It's because of the Meta class NewForm I don't want to add in model = Address again for NewForm as it should get it from OldForm. Maybe some sort of super? I just want to overwrite fields in NewForn

Comment: I think ProffesotDante is right, I was wondering whether by giving your child a meta it ignored the parent. There's nothing about it in the docs, but I guess that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit your Meta class too:

```
class NewForm(OldForm):
    name = Name()


    class Meta(OldForm.Meta):
        fields = ('name', 'address')
```

Then your NewForm class has its model set as Address.